# Learning Control-M

Tags: cron, job-control

Please recommend an approach to achieving familiarity, fluency, and eventually expertise in Control-M.  The immediate problem domain is "potent stakeholders have urged the migration of a zoo of hundreds of cron jobs, some quite elderly, to Control-M," and the immediate platform is Solaris.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the job scheduler on Control-M works, but it is quite easy to fake a Control-M environment for testing an app.  It has shell script scaffolding on unix and batch files on Windows.

I found it quite easy to emulate Control-M for the purposes of testing offline running of a job.  This was achieved by taking one of its template scripts and modifying it.  It took about half a day to get working - mainly tracing back through its other scripts to find the origin of some of the variables.

I'm guessing the the job scheduler's bark is probably worse than its bite.  The scripts should give you some insight into how it handles error conditions.